# C# Pinvoke Delphi ShortString System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, delphi, pinvoke

My client just sent me a delphi dll to be consumed for my asp.net app, and below is the dll's signature:

```
function GerarChave(pChave: ShortString; pData: ShortString; pAcao: ShortString): PAnsiChar; stdcall;
```

How should I call it? I've tried everything like

```
[DllImport("CEIINT.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint = "GerarChave")]
    public static extern string GerarChave([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]string pChave, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]string pData, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]string pAcao);

string chave = "ABC123";
string data = "19/09/2019";
string acao = "0";
GerarChave(chave, data, acao);
```

but I always get a System.AccessViolationException error which says:

> System.AccessViolationException... Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Could anybody help me please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Delphi shortstring matches no pinvoke type. Get the dll vendor to supply a dll using interop types.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan According to http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.ShortString the memory size is fixed at 256 bytes. So it should be marshallable as either a `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=256)` whereas in the DllImport-Attribute the CharSet parameter should be set to `CharSet.Ansi` or a byte array with `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=256)`. Of course, the first character must be manually read/written as the length.

Comment: @ckuri Wrong. The first byte is the string length.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's what I said with "Of course, the first character must be manually read/written as the length".

Comment: Going to be hard to get that first byte in there in general since you'd need to account for the local ANSI charset and hope that you can encode all chars greater than 127 in UTF16. Which I suppose you will always be able to do but not going to be much fun. If you had to do this you'd handle the encoding yourself and marshal as byte array. Better to fix the bogus DLL.

Comment: The author of the DLL should read my article: [DLL dos and don'ts](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html). He or she is making the mistake of communicating through a Delphi-specific type. That is a horrible thing to do when writing a DLL. The article discusses this and gives alternatives so that any language can use the DLL.

Answer (score 3):

Like David Heffernan said, you should try to get back to your client to request a DLL with more interoperable types.

If you have no other choice you could try to do the conversions manually, first by changing the signature to an byte array:

```
[DllImport("CEIINT.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint = "GerarChave")]
public static extern string GerarChave(
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=256)] byte[] pChave, 
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=256)] byte[] pData, 
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=256)] byte[] pAcao);
```

Then define the following method to convert a string to a Delphi ShortString:

```
public byte[] GetDelphiShortString(string str)
{
  var bytes = new byte[256];
  bytes[0] = (byte)Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str, 0, str.Length, bytes, 1);
  return bytes;
}
```

Finally, you should be able to call the Delphi function via:

```
GerarChave(GetDelphiShortString(chave), GetDelphiShortString(data), GetDelphiShortString(acao));
```

Comment: No. This doesn't work at all. You can't cast a byte array to a byte. And even if you could it wouldn't be right. You need the first byte to be the length. And the remaining bytes to be the payload. Get the byte array. Move its length into byte 0. Copy the next 255 bytes to the rest of the array.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not casting a byte array to a byte: [GetBytes with 5 arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c20ss51h(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the number of bytes written. This GetBytes overload will convert the string to a pre-existing byte array, put it the decoded bytes at position 1 and then the result (the bytes written) will be written to byte 0. No array copying needed.

Comment: OK, you are right, mea culpa. Going to be worth throwing if the number of bytes is greater than 255.

Comment: True, but it would make the code more complicated and as a ShortString doesn't support such long strings anyway an Exception may be fine. Also ultimately it's up to the OP how he wants to handle long strings.

Comment: Actually the other problem is the return value. Your code will call CoTaskMemAlloc to deallocate the string. That won't end well.

Comment: Do you mean the return value of `GerarChave`? Wouldn't the C# marshalling just copy the value into the managed string and leave the PAnsiChar as is, because it's the responsibility of the one who allocated the memory for PAnsiChar (here Delphi) to deallocate it?

Comment: No. It calls CoTaskMemFree in it. Who knows how it was allocated. Almost certainly its a Delphi string variable that is deallocated when the function returns. Yet again a problem with the DLL and one that can't be fixed from the outside.

Comment: No matter how the string is allocated, it is pretty clear that the authors of the DLL should never have used a ShortString. If someone gave me such a DLL, with such a stupid mistake, I'd be a little wary of the quality of the rest of the DLL. Anyway, who on earth still uses ShortString these days, even in a non-DLL setting?